# Meaning of "ihrerseits"

Tags: meaning

> Sollte keine Einigung erzielt werden, droht den USA Mitte des Monats die Zahlungsunfähigkeit, die ihrerseits schwerwiegende Folgen für die Weltwirtschaft haben könnte.

The meaning of [ihrerseits](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/ihrerseits) is "for their part". However, I can't quite see how it fits in here. Does it mean more like "in turn" (i.e. "wiederum") here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Ihrerseits* means there *for her part* (in this case, as infered from the context, not the third person in plural). Meaning that, *for the part of the* **Zahlungsunfähigkeit**, not from the part of the USA.

Actually I don't see any problem with your interpretation either: for *wiederum* stands for *meinerseits, deinerseits, ihrerseits,...* (c.f. [3rd meaning here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wiederum))

Comment: Just to clarify: the adverb 'ihrerseits' can be referring to a plural 3rd-person (and, when capitalised, the formal 2nd-person 'you') as well as the feminine 3rd-person singular. In this quote it's the feminine singular because it refers to the feminine noun *Zahlungsunfähigkeit*.